# Attach UncaughtExceptionHandler to a TimerTask

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is it possible to attach an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to a `TimerTask`?

(Other than by calling `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a `TimerTask` proxy that catches `Throwable` from `run`.

```
public final class TimerTaskCatcher extends TimerTask {
    private final TimerTask orig;
    private final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler;
    public TimerTaskCatcher(
        TimerTask orig, 
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler
    ) {
        if (orig == null || handler == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.orig = orig;
        this.handler = handler;
    }
    @Override public boolean cancel() {
        // **Edit:** Correction report due to @Discape.
        // In fact, this entire method could be elided.
        boolean weirdResult;
        try {
            orig.cancel();
        } finally {
            weirdResult = super.cancel();
        }
        return weirdResult;
    }
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            orig.run();
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            handler.uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), exc);
        }
    }
    @Override public long scheduledExecutionTime() {
        return orig.scheduledExecutionTime();
    }
}
```

BTW: You might want to consider using `java.util.concurrent` instead of `Timer`.

Comment: For some reason cancel() doesn't work. https://imgur.com/a/u6RP06d

Comment: @Discape Yup. (`Timer` uses a backdoor to access `TimerTask`). cancel corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so. There's an instance method ([setUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/langThread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))) in `Thread` `class` that set's the thread's `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

In your `run` method of the `TimerTask` you can do something like this:

```
public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(eh);
}
```